# Form-Submit from Client to PHP: is the sequence of fields reliable?

Tags: php, forms, client, sequence, server

I am working on a very complex form that can be completly customized by the user with JavaScript. This can end up in hundreds of fields (including a lot of hidden meta information).

I would like to know if there is any way the correct sequence of form elements (their sequence within the HTML code) can be corrupted on their way from "client browser A" (e.g. Firefox) to "server-side scripting language B" (e.g. PHP).

W3C only [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13): "A form data set is a sequence of control-name/current-value pairs..." which leads me to assume that this sequence should be persistent during the whole form post process.

**Can I completely rely on the correctness of the field sequence when submitting from any browser to (in my case) PHP?**

**Or do I have to double check?**

---

In case my question is not clear, here is a simplified example.

1) the server delivers this form:

```
<input type="text" name="servergenerated_formfield_1" value="position 1">
<input type="text" name="servergenerated_formfield_2" value="position 2">
<input type="text" name="servergenerated_formfield_3" value="position 3">
```

2) the user creates 2 new form elements using Javascript:

```
<input type="text" name="USERGENERATED_FORMFIELD_1" value="lorem ipsum">
<input type="text" name="servergenerated_formfield_1" value="position 1">
<input type="text" name="servergenerated_formfield_2" value="position 2">
<input type="text" name="USERGENERATED_FORMFIELD_2" value="dolor sit amet">
<input type="text" name="servergenerated_formfield_3" value="position 3">
```

3) Now when I access the array (using PHP):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key.': '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

**... is there ANY chance I might end up with something ELSE than this?**

```
// output
USERGENERATED_FORMFIELD_1: lorem ipsum
servergenerated_formfield_1: position 1
servergenerated_formfield_2: position 2
USERGENERATED_FORMFIELD_2: dolor sit amet
servergenerated_formfield_3: position 3
```

Comment: Are you worried that the order will change, or the the names will change? The names, won't change, so the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, it's the order I am worried about. In above example there is no way to restore the correct order if the sequence is corrupted during transfer.

Comment: As I say, the names won't change, so the order doesn't matter, does it? If the order does matter, then you could pass some hidden field that specifies the order of the form elements.

Comment: i don't know whether the order changes or not, but why are you worrying about it since you already save the index as a part of the field name, later on the server you can parse the input array names and sort as u like

Comment: @vascowhite: Well, that's exactly my question. Is there a need to do that?

Comment: @vascowhite just for clarification, may be he needs the order in which fields were created, that depends on his problem domain

Comment: @Abdo Adel: it's a little more complicated if you think my example through. It would be easy with a static form, but this one is highly dynamic.

Comment: I guess that depends on your use case. I believe that the order will be preserved, but I've never been in a position where it matters, so I've never paid much attention to it.

Comment: @user2542746 I take it you want to be able to reproduce the user generated form?

Comment: @user2542746 static or dynamic it does not matter, you have an associative array of name/value elements, the sub string after the last '_' corresponds to the index which represents the priority of this item, use that priority to sort the elements (it's all ready made for you, substring - last _ - sort - queue ....)

Comment: @Abdo Adel: no, it's about the sequence of fields in the HTML code. The USERGENERATED_FORMFIELD_* in my example would make sequentation a pain in the a** - that's the reason for my question.

Btw.: I already have a prototype for that backcheck. But it's buggy, which is no surprice given the complexity (my example is very simplified). I want to kick all that code out and rather depend on standars.

Comment: @AbdoAdel but that doesn't tell him whether user field 1 comes before or after server field 1.

Comment: @user2542746 going by your replies, I think you will need to put some mechanism in place to make the order of the fields explicit.

Comment: @vascowhite: exactly. The user saves the form and can change it later. It's a custom blog system for travellers. Articles tend to contain +50 photos and huge amounts of text.

Comment: @user2542746 you ought to indicate that from the very beginnig

Comment: @AbdoAdel: I just specified this.

Comment: If sequence is so important, you might be better off using Ajax to submit the data so that you can control the order of fields.